# WebView clears the history item on lock screen

Tags: android, webview

I have a website and few of its pages contains back button and its working fine in WebView until I lock the screen,So when I come back from lock screen the websites back button is not working I debug the code and found that the WebView history Items removed after coming back from lock screen except current item. I checked the WebView method `webView.canGoBack()` and its returning false after coming back from lock screen.so is there any way to retain back stack history items of WebView. thanks